# Using SVN, how can I compare a tag/path against non-versioned files?

Tags: svn

Let's say I have a set of source files on disk, and the same application in SVN. I'd like to compare these files with a particular repository path, for example to see if the files on disk actually are the same as a particular tag.

svn diff doesn't work in this case because the files on disk aren't a working copy.

Obviously I could check out or export the tag I'm interested in to a temporary location and then diff, but I'm hoping to find an option that doesn't involve a whole second copy of the files living on disk.

(My overall goal for this is to audit for changes on live web app files that haven't made it to source control)

Comment: Why is it not a working copy?

Comment: Well, if it was a working copy, there wouldn't be a question because svn status would solve it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You realllly raellly should consider using `rsync --dry-run -acp devbox:/workingCopy server:/liveCopy` for the comparison. That's how I do audits across the huge clusters I maintain...

Comment: This is a reasonable alternative to diff if you have the files on disk already

Answer (score 0):

For repo-objects you can|have to use `svn cat URL`, which output target's content (and fix broken workflow after it)